# Manipulate Data to retrieve specific digit

Tags: sql, database, string, oracle, plsql

I have a Table with a Column like this:

```
Location 
19.15
19.14
19.13
18.01
18.02
```

I searched for function to retrieve just 2 digit from beginning to be like this:

```
Location 
19
19
19
18
18
```

Unfortunately I can't find solution yet .

Comment: What happens if you have three digits on the front?  Eg, `100.01`?  Or just one?  `1.999999`?  Is the column text/character, or decimal/floating point?  Is the output supposed to be a number, or the characters?  Why are you trying to get just the first two characters?

Answer (score 1):

```
select cast(location as int) as location
from your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on the data type.

We can return the first two characters of a string column with the SUBSTR() function:

```
select substr(location, 1, 2) as location
from your_table;
```

If you wish to handle a varying number of digits before the point then perhaps a regular expression function would be better:

```
select regexp_substr(location, '([0-9]+)\.(.*)', 1, 1, 'i', 1)) as location
from your_table;
```

If location is a numeric and you want to remove the trailing decimals you can use TRUNC() like this:

```
select trunc(location) as location
from your_table;
```